# Pgfplot/tikzpicture: modify ticks and labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, labels

I would like to modify my tikzpicture:

1.) I added an `extra tick` at `x=92`, but this overlaps with the automatic tick x=100. How to solve this overlapping? Same problem for the second extra tick at `x=153.3` (which is actually the fraction 460/3 - how to label fractions?).

2.) I used `\filldraw` to create circles at intersections points. How to create a relative node as a label, like `\node[] at (200,150) {p = MC}`?

3.) Furthermore it would be nice to add additional labels `(MC, MR, p)` to the lines in relative positions.

```
\documentclass[13pt,a4paper,headlines=6,headinclude=true]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
  \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,xmin=0,xmax=349,ymin=0,ymax=549,
    extra x ticks={92},
        extra y ticks={20, 153.3},
    xlabel=$\scriptstyle x$,
    ylabel=$\scriptstyle p$,
    tick label style={font=\tiny}, 
        legend style={font=\tiny, at={(1.2,0.8)},anchor=outer north east, draw=none, cells={anchor=west},fill=gray,fill opacity=0.4,text opacity =1}
        ]
        \addplot[no marks,red,domain=0:250,samples=250, thick] {x};
        \addlegendentry{$MC(x)=x$};
        \addplot+[no marks,orange,domain=0:230,samples=150, thick] {460-2*(x)};
        \addlegendentry{$p(x)=460-2x$};
        \addplot+[no marks,yellow,domain=0:230,samples=150, thick] {460-4*(x)};
        \addlegendentry{$MR(x)=460-4x$};
        \path[draw=gray] (0,460/3) -- (460/3,460/3); 
        \path[draw=gray] (460/3,0) -- (460/3,460/3); 
        \path[draw=gray, dashed, thick] (92,0) -- (92,276); 
        \path[draw=gray, dashed, thick] (0,276) -- (92,276); 
        \filldraw (92,276) circle (1pt);
        \filldraw (460/3,460/3) circle (1pt);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thank you :)

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are lot of questions and I did lot of modifications, hence there is no point in giving the list of modifications made. Please study the code:

```
\documentclass[13pt,a4paper,headlines=6,headinclude=true]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
  \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,xmin=0,xmax=349,ymin=0,ymax=549,
    extra x ticks={92,153.3},
    extra x tick labels={$92\rightarrow$,$153.3\rightarrow$},
    extra y ticks={20, 153.3},
    extra x tick style={ticklabel style={rotate=35,yshift=2pt,anchor=east,inner xsep=2pt}},
    xlabel=$\scriptstyle x$,
    ylabel=$\scriptstyle p$,
    tick label style={font=\tiny},
        legend style={font=\tiny, legend pos=outer north east, draw=none, cells={anchor=west},fill=gray,fill opacity=0.4,text opacity =1}
        ]
        \addplot[no marks,red,domain=0:250,samples=250, thick,name path=red] {x}node[pos=0.95,below,text=black,font=\tiny]{$MC$};
        \addlegendentry{$MC(x)=x$};
        \addplot+[no marks,orange,domain=0:230,samples=150, thick,name path=orange] {460-2*(x)}node[pos=0.95,above,xshift=3pt,text=black,font=\tiny]{$MR$};
        \addlegendentry{$p(x)=460-2x$};
        \addplot+[no marks,yellow,domain=0:120,samples=150, thick,name path=yellow] {460-4*(x)}node[pos=0.95,above,xshift=3pt,text=black,font=\tiny]{$p$};
        \addlegendentry{$MR(x)=460-4x$};
        \path[draw=gray] (0,460/3) -- (460/3,460/3);
        \path[draw=gray] (460/3,0) -- (460/3,460/3);
        \path[draw=gray, dashed, thick] (92,0) -- (92,276);
        \path[draw=gray, dashed, thick] (0,276) -- (92,276);
        \path[name intersections={of= orange and red, by=aa}];
        \path[name intersections={of= yellow and red, by=bb}];
        \filldraw (92,276) circle (1pt)node[right,font=\tiny] {label H};
        \filldraw (aa) circle (1pt)node[right,font=\tiny,yshift=-1pt] {label G};
        \filldraw (bb) circle (1pt)node[right,font=\tiny,yshift=-1pt] {label I};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is another option where you put the extra x tick labels yourself.

```
\documentclass[13pt,a4paper,headlines=6,headinclude=true]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
  \begin{axis}[clip=false,axis lines=middle,xmin=0,xmax=349,ymin=0,ymax=549,
    %extra x ticks={92,153.3},
%    extra x tick labels={$92\rightarrow$,$153.3\rightarrow$},
    extra y ticks={20, 153.3},
    %extra x tick style={ticklabel style={rotate=35,yshift=2pt,anchor=east,inner xsep=2pt}},
    xlabel=$\scriptstyle x$,
    ylabel=$\scriptstyle p$,
    tick label style={font=\tiny},
        legend style={font=\tiny, legend pos=outer north east, draw=none, cells={anchor=west},fill=gray,fill opacity=0.4,text opacity =1}
        ]
        \addplot[no marks,red,domain=0:250,samples=250, thick,name path=red] {x}node[pos=0.95,below,text=black,font=\tiny]{$MC$};
        \addlegendentry{$MC(x)=x$};
        \addplot+[no marks,orange,domain=0:230,samples=150, thick,name path=orange] {460-2*(x)}node[pos=0.95,above,xshift=3pt,text=black,font=\tiny]{$MR$};
        \addlegendentry{$p(x)=460-2x$};
        \addplot+[no marks,yellow,domain=0:120,samples=150, thick,name path=yellow] {460-4*(x)}node[pos=0.95,above,xshift=3pt,text=black,font=\tiny]{$p$};
        \addlegendentry{$MR(x)=460-4x$};
        \path[draw=gray] (0,460/3) -- (460/3,460/3);
        \path[draw=gray] (460/3,0) -- (460/3,460/3);
        \path[draw=gray, dashed, thick] (92,0) -- (92,276);
        \path[draw=gray, dashed, thick] (0,276) -- (92,276);
        \path[name intersections={of= orange and red, by=aa}];
        \path[name intersections={of= yellow and red, by=bb}];
        \filldraw (92,276) circle (1pt)node[right,font=\tiny] {label H};
        \filldraw (aa) circle (1pt)node[right,font=\tiny,yshift=-1pt] {label G};
        \filldraw (bb) circle (1pt)node[right,font=\tiny,yshift=-1pt] {label I};

        \node[font=\tiny,inner sep=1pt,] (92) at (80,-50) {$92$};
        \draw[-stealth]  (92) -- ++(0,2) -- (92,0);
        \node[font=\tiny,inner sep=1pt,] (153) at (170,-50) {$153.33$};
        \draw[-stealth]  (153) -- ++(0,2) -- (153.33,0);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is again very useful Harish! Studying/reading your code is great fun and very instructive :-)